# SOQL Query on bithdate

Tags: apex, soql, query

SOQL Query On Birhtdate ,Find the birthday of all contacts born in the year 2000 and  Do not include contacts born in the month of May.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, BirthDate 
FROM Contact 
WHERE CALENDAR_MONTH(BirthDate) != 5 
    AND CALENDAR_YEAR(BirthDate) = 2000
```

Here is the list of all [SOQL Date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Birthdate FROM Contact WHERE Birthdate>=2000-01-01 AND Birthdate<=2000-12-31 AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Birthdate)!=5
```

Comment: This answer is pretty much a strict downgrade from the approach you already accepted.